# How to convert date format in SQL Query Results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-formatting

I want to display Date fields in SQL Query Results as **DD-MM-YYYY** Format. In table it is vice versa. When I try with below query it does not works.

**SQL Query Link: (Tables can be retrieved by clicking Employees and Orders links under "SQLSERVER Database:" section)**

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysqlserver.asp?filename=trysql_func_sqlserver_convert3

**SQL Query I used:**

```
select
a.EmployeeID,
a.BirthDate CONVERT(datetime, 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
b.OrderID,
b.OrderDate CONVERT(datetime, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
from
Employees a, Orders b
where
a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID;
```

Comment: Hint:  `FORMAT()`:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: I suggest you format data in the application rather than T-SQL.

Comment: It's long past time you started using ANSI-92 JOIN syntax as well; it's been around for 28 years now. I also recommend using good aliases. `Employees` starts with an `E`, not an `a`, and `Orders` starts with an `O`, not a `b`. [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) & [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query;

```
select
a.EmployeeID,
CONVERT(varchar, a.BirthDate, 105) as BirthDate,
b.OrderID,
CONVERT(varchar,b.OrderDate ,105) as OrderDate
from
Employees a, Orders b
where
a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
```

[image]

Comment: demote because you use convert to varchar rather than char and without a length.

Comment: SMor check out the link https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Comment: @esat just because an article uses bad habits doesn't mean you should follow them. Check out this one, for example: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: always declare the length otherwise beware the truncate